# throw exceptions for unknown Spring properties

Tags: spring, spring-boot, configuration, fail-fast

I made a very silly mistake in my Spring Boot app's YAML config:

```
---
spring:
    profiles: local
...
___
spring:
    profiles: foo
...
---
spring:
    profiles:
        active: bar
        include: foo
...
```

I accidentally tried to use "spring.profiles.active" to set the Spring profiles in the last section. Since this does not mean anything to Spring, the last section was always applied and the `foo` profile was always turned on.

`spring.profiles.active` is essentially nonsense, yet the app ran without complaint (until the problematic configuration caused other problems).

I would like to configure Spring somehow to immediately throw an exception when it encounters a config parameter that appears internal (`spring...`) but is unknown to it. How do I do this?